# Is this sentence correct "We are going shopping mall"

Tags: prepositions

The statement above does not have 'to' before the destination. We can write 'going home' without 'to'. Where else can we skip 'to'?

Comment: Add a comma after *going* and you'd have a grammatical sentence telling the shopping mall that you're leaving. In AuE (and BrE and probably AmE), you'll need "to the" before *shopping mall* to get what you're after.

Comment: “We are going shopping at the mall” “We are going to the mall”

Comment: We can also skip 'to' when going in, out, up, down, through, around etc.

Comment: No, the sentence is not correct. It is not grammatical and it is not idiomatic.

Comment: We can speak of _going abroad_ or _overseas_.

Comment: There's always "We're going malling."

Comment: When *home* is used without *to*, it functions as an adverb, not as a noun; *mall* is not used as an adverb (although there is no guarantee that somebody won't start using it that way someday).

Comment: There are actually some BrE dialects that allow "to" to be omitted in this scenario. But it wouldn't be standard English and it wouldn't get you as many marks in an exam or come across as well in an interview.

Answer (score 1):

**[home](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/home)** is a strange word. It can be a noun:

> Our **home** is in the centre of town

It can also (and this is unusual) be an adverb:

> I usually go **home** at about 5pm

**shopping mall** is a noun and, like most nouns, it cannot be used as an adverb. You can make a noun into an adverbial phrase by adding a preposition:

> ... to the shopping mall
>   ... at the shopping mall
>   ... from the shopping mall

Your sentence is therefore only correct if you add a preposition and a determiner (a or the):

> We are going **to the** shopping mall

English is not the only language to treat home as a special case, though treating home as an adverb is unusual: most languages have a special verb for coming/going home- rentrer in french, rawwah in Egyptian Arabic, pulang in Indonesian.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave off "mall" then the sentence is correct: We are going shopping. Otherwise, @Lawrence is correct, you would need "to the" before "shopping mall".